# accessing other php script resources/variables

Tags: php, variables, command-line-interface

Well, i was searching for a while and Couldn't find any solution or workaround for accessing other php script.

I have a script that is running in **CLI**, u guessed its a socket server, and of course it have variables, objects, arrays, etc...

I need to debug this file without the need of printing/ echoing the variables from the script itself, I know you can do it but its kinda messy and for the long run you will end up increasing your file size just with commented and unwanted line of codes, that will took time to clean up later on. and plus I need to make a sort of a command line interface for that server in the future.

so my question is there any way to read or debug the script variables from another script running in another CLI instance? ( i can included it but it will be another instance with other values/variables)
in Addition, can I run a specific function from outside of that script? do I use reflections ?

I tried _SESSION but I cannot access it while the server is running.

In C# or Java you can.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible, but i would suggest other solution than "inspecting" variables in running script. I would use db to store logs about current operation and it's variables. It could be managed by config written in db to write all logs or only important ones, so You could easily disable log output just by changing one row in db.

Comment: I thought of it, but i dont want to make the server busy and hanging when accessing the Db to store data... its a socket server in the end

Comment: You can measure the load of that solution. It would be just inserts (if you wont uses keys on table it will be very fast) and you can check config less frequent.

Comment: as far as i can tell you, the server is very busy :P, im trying to implement a multi thread solution to handle it. but meanwhile you I need to check and ,sort of, handle its debugging from another CLI, its better in the long run, maybe ill create a CLI script that will manage and control that server

Comment: You could implement method returning via echo your desired values on some event happened maybe it would be useful http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php

Comment: haha, the first comment in php "Remember that declaring a tick handler can become really expensive in terms of CPU cycles: Every n ticks the signal handling overhead will be executed.", but its kinda interesting, I 'll research it :)